# Difference between 2$\pi f$ and $\omega$ in Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, notation

What is the difference when we use $e^{-j2\pi f}$ and $e^{-j\omega n}$ for Fourier transformation?

Comment: $\omega = 2\pi f$

Comment: @endolith Thanks :) I know that, but I don't know how the meaning of Fourier transform and Fourier transform table pairs change if we use $f$ or $\omega$, Can you help me with that?

Comment: It's exactly the same thing, just expressed in different units.  You should really be comparing $e^{-j\omega}$ with $e^{-j\omega n}$, for instance.

Comment: An interesting side note: white noise has (two-sided) power spectral density $\frac{N_0}{2}$ regardless of whether you are denoting it $S_N(\omega)$ or as  $S_n(f)$ !! In either case, the noise power in a bandwidth of $B$ Hz works out to be $N_0B$ watts or volts$^2$.

Comment: Thank @endolith, What about normalization coefficient? As I know it is different in use of $f$ and $\omega$? Is there any pattern for this difference?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Oh! That's interesting Dilip, is it not true for other types of signals but white noise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be mixing two concepts, pertaining to (following Robert Bristow-Johnson)

- the "analog context" (more formally, the "continuous-time case"),
- the "digital context" (more formally the "discrete-time case").

The first concept corresponds to the continuous Fourier transform, for which you can use 
a form of  normalized frequency cycles per second or Hertz ($e^{-j2\pi f}$), while the second is the angular frequency in radians per second ($e^{-j\omega}$).

The second one, with integer index $n$ relates first instance to discrete summations, e.g. the discrete-time Fourier transform (DTFT), where the Fourier kernel writes  $e^{-j2\pi f n}$ with $f\in \mathbb{R}$ (for instance) or $e^{-j\omega n}$ with $\omega\in \mathbb{R}$ (for instance).

The first concept is in use in the inverse DTFT, since it involves integrals.

Comment: i would say, in the *"analog case"* (more formally, the *"continuous-time case"*) it's $$ \Omega = 2\pi f$$ and in the *"digital case"* (more formally the *"discrete-time case"*) it's $$ \omega = 2\pi \frac{f}{f_\text{s}} $$ in my book it's $$ s=j \Omega $$ and $$ z = e^{j \omega} $$

Comment: "in my book" is meant as a figure of speech.